# blacklist ethernet driver

Tags: 12.10, blacklist

I'm using Quantal Quetzal 12.10 How can I find out what my ethernet's driver is and how can I blacklist it? Since I believe it is the source of driver conflict in my machine, I would like to try it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find out the kernel module

```
dmesg | grep eth0
```

This gives me

```
[    4.655121] sky2 0000:07:00.0: eth0: addr 00:23:54:7c:a9:fa
```

Meaning that sky2 is the kernel module used for eth0.

Then you could blacklist the module by

```
echo 'blacklist sky2' > /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-sky2.conf
update-initramfs -k all -u
```

Reboot the machine. To remove the blacklist just do

```
rm /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-sky2.conf
update-initramfs -k all -u
```