# Network cable unplugged message after Motherboard change

Tags: 12.04, networking, drivers, ethernet

SOLVED!!!  Jan 1, 2014. (see last edit)

The motherboard on my win PC blew the PCI-EX slot, so I had to swap it to my Ubuntu box.
Everything works fine except the NIC. I keep getting a cable unplugged message.
The NIC works fine in Win XP ( Dual Boot setup) so it is not hardware related.
Ubuntu 12.04 does not "see the OnBoard NIC Marvell 88E8056.

I have downloaded and installed the sk98lin driver module from Marvel.
It shows up as a kernel module. but Ubuntu keeps loading the old sky2 driver module.
I have tried "Blacklisting" the sky2 module but it keeps loading it.

Here are relevant terminal outputs:

```
hans@hans-GA-78LMT-S2P:~$ lspci -k | grep -A5 Ethernet 
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88E8056 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 20) 
    Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. Device 0e0a 
    Kernel driver in use: sky2 
    Kernel modules: sk98lin, sky2 

hans@hans-GA-78LMT-S2P:~$ ifconfig -a 
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1c:25:51:24:43  
          inet6 addr: fe80::21c:25ff:fe51:2443/64 Scope:Link 
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1 
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 
          TX packets:304 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:69952 (69.9 KB) 
          Interrupt:19 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0 
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host 
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1 
          RX packets:168 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 
          TX packets:168 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:13344 (13.3 KB)  TX bytes:13344 (13.3 KB)
```

Does anyone have a solution to the problem?
If so, Please be specific and clear, please.
I have been around computers for a long time ( remember punchcards?) but am a real NOOB at Linux type systems.

## Requested info:

Here is the content of the 70 persistent-net rules file :

```
# This file was automatically generated by the /lib/udev/write_net_rules 
# program, run by the persistent-net-generator.rules rules file. 
# 
# You can modify it, as long as you keep each rule on a single 
# line, and change only the value of the NAME= key. 

# PCI device 0x1969:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:06.0/0000:02:00.0 (atl1c) 
#SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="90:2b:34:ad:c3:22", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0" 

# PCI device 0x11ab:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:02:00.0 (sky2) 
#SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:1c:25:51:24:43", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth1" 

# PCI device 0x11ab:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:02:00.0 (sk98lin) 
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="sk98lin", ATTR{address}=="00:1c:25:51:24:43", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0" 

# PCI device 0x11ab:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:02:00.0 (sky2) 
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:1c:25:51:24:43", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth1"
```

**Extra output asked for:**

Newly auto-generated 70-persistant-net.rules file after deleting the old:

```
# This file was automatically generated by the /lib/udev/write_net_rules 
# program, run by the persistent-net-generator.rules rules file. 
# 
# You can modify it, as long as you keep each rule on a single 
# line, and change only the value of the NAME= key. 

# PCI device 0x11ab:/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:07.0/0000:02:00.0 (sky2) 
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="00:1c:25:51:24:43", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"
```

lsmod & modinfo:

```
hans@hans-GA-78LMT-S2P:~$ lsmod | grep "sk98\|sky" 
sky2                   59043  0 


hans@hans-GA-78LMT-S2P:~$ modinfo sky2 
filename:       /lib/modules/3.2.0-39-generic/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/marvell/sky2.ko 
version:        1.30 
license:        GPL 
author:         Stephen Hemminger <shemminger@linux-foundation.org> 
description:    Marvell Yukon 2 Gigabit Ethernet driver 
srcversion:     973DE291F18F5911153FD7C 
alias:          pci:v000011ABd00004381sv*sd*bc*sc*i* 
alias:          pci:v000011ABd00004380sv*sd*bc*sc*i* 
alias:          pci:v000011ABd00004370sv*sd*bc*sc*i* 
alias:          pci:v000011ABd0000436Dsv*sd*bc*sc*i* 
alias:          pci:v000011ABd0000436Csv*sd*bc*sc*i* 
alias:          pci:v000011ABd0000436Bsv*sd*bc*sc*i* 
alias:          pci:v000011ABd0000436Asv*sd*bc*sc*i* 
alias:          pci:v000011ABd00004369sv*sd*bc*sc*i* 
alias:          pci:v000011ABd00004368sv*sd*bc*sc*i* 
alias:          pci:v000011ABd00004367sv*sd*bc*sc*i* 
alias:          pci:v000011ABd00004366sv*sd*bc*sc*i* 
alias:          pci:v000011ABd00004365sv*sd*bc*sc*i* 
alias:          pci:v000011ABd00004364sv*sd*bc*sc*i* 
alias:          pci:v000011ABd00004363sv*sd*bc*sc*i* 
alias:          pci:v000011ABd00004362sv*sd*bc*sc*i* 
alias:          pci:v000011ABd00004361sv*sd*bc*sc*i* 
alias:          pci:v000011ABd00004360sv*sd*bc*sc*i* 
alias:          pci:v000011ABd0000435Asv*sd*bc*sc*i* 
alias:          pci:v000011ABd00004357sv*sd*bc*sc*i* 
alias:          pci:v000011ABd00004356sv*sd*bc*sc*i* 
alias:          pci:v000011ABd00004355sv*sd*bc*sc*i* 
alias:          pci:v000011ABd00004354sv*sd*bc*sc*i* 
alias:          pci:v000011ABd00004353sv*sd*bc*sc*i* 
alias:          pci:v000011ABd00004352sv*sd*bc*sc*i* 
alias:          pci:v000011ABd00004351sv*sd*bc*sc*i* 
alias:          pci:v000011ABd00004350sv*sd*bc*sc*i* 
alias:          pci:v000011ABd00004347sv*sd*bc*sc*i* 
alias:          pci:v000011ABd00004346sv*sd*bc*sc*i* 
alias:          pci:v000011ABd00004345sv*sd*bc*sc*i* 
alias:          pci:v000011ABd00004344sv*sd*bc*sc*i* 
alias:          pci:v000011ABd00004343sv*sd*bc*sc*i* 
alias:          pci:v000011ABd00004342sv*sd*bc*sc*i* 
alias:          pci:v000011ABd00004341sv*sd*bc*sc*i* 
alias:          pci:v000011ABd00004340sv*sd*bc*sc*i* 
alias:          pci:v00001186d00004B03sv*sd*bc*sc*i* 
alias:          pci:v00001186d00004B02sv*sd*bc*sc*i* 
alias:          pci:v00001186d00004001sv*sd*bc*sc*i* 
alias:          pci:v00001186d00004B00sv*sd*bc*sc*i* 
alias:          pci:v00001148d00009E01sv*sd*bc*sc*i* 
alias:          pci:v00001148d00009E00sv*sd*bc*sc*i* 
alias:          pci:v00001148d00009000sv*sd*bc*sc*i* 
depends:        
intree:         Y 
vermagic:       3.2.0-39-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           debug:Debug level (0=none,...,16=all) (int) 
parm:           copybreak:Receive copy threshold (int) 
parm:           disable_msi:Disable Message Signaled Interrupt (MSI) (int) 
parm:           legacy_pme:Legacy power management (int) 


hans@hans-GA-78LMT-S2P:~$ modinfo sk98lin 
filename:       /lib/modules/3.2.0-39-generic/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/marvell/sk98lin.ko 
version:        10.93.3.3 
license:        GPL 
description:    Marvell/SysKonnect Yukon Ethernet Network Driver 
author:         Mirko Lindner <support@marvell.com> 
srcversion:     B6855C93810A36F7A9088B6 
alias:          pci:v000011ABd00005005sv*sd*bc*sc*i* 
alias:          pci:v000011ABd00004382sv*sd*bc*sc*i* 
alias:          pci:v000011ABd00004381sv*sd*bc*sc*i* 
alias:          pci:v000011ABd00004380sv*sd*bc*sc*i* 
alias:          pci:v000011ABd00004370sv*sd*bc*sc*i* 
alias:          pci:v000011ABd0000436Dsv*sd*bc*sc*i* 
alias:          pci:v000011ABd0000436Csv*sd*bc*sc*i* 
alias:          pci:v000011ABd0000436Bsv*sd*bc*sc*i* 
alias:          pci:v000011ABd00004369sv*sd*bc*sc*i* 
alias:          pci:v000011ABd00004368sv*sd*bc*sc*i* 
alias:          pci:v000011ABd00004367sv*sd*bc*sc*i* 
alias:          pci:v000011ABd00004366sv*sd*bc*sc*i* 
alias:          pci:v000011ABd00004365sv*sd*bc*sc*i* 
alias:          pci:v000011ABd00004364sv*sd*bc*sc*i* 
alias:          pci:v000011ABd00004363sv*sd*bc*sc*i* 
alias:          pci:v000011ABd00004362sv*sd*bc*sc*i* 
alias:          pci:v000011ABd0000435Asv*sd*bc*sc*i* 
alias:          pci:v000011ABd00004357sv*sd*bc*sc*i* 
alias:          pci:v000011ABd00004356sv*sd*bc*sc*i* 
alias:          pci:v000011ABd00004355sv*sd*bc*sc*i* 
alias:          pci:v000011ABd00004354sv*sd*bc*sc*i* 
alias:          pci:v000011ABd00004353sv*sd*bc*sc*i* 
alias:          pci:v000011ABd00004352sv*sd*bc*sc*i* 
alias:          pci:v000011ABd00004350sv*sd*bc*sc*i* 
alias:          pci:v000011ABd00004347sv*sd*bc*sc*i* 
alias:          pci:v000011ABd00004346sv*sd*bc*sc*i* 
alias:          pci:v000011ABd00004345sv*sd*bc*sc*i* 
alias:          pci:v000011ABd00004344sv*sd*bc*sc*i* 
alias:          pci:v000011ABd00004343sv*sd*bc*sc*i* 
alias:          pci:v000011ABd00004342sv*sd*bc*sc*i* 
alias:          pci:v000011ABd00004341sv*sd*bc*sc*i* 
alias:          pci:v000011ABd00004340sv*sd*bc*sc*i* 
alias:          pci:v000011ABd00004320sv*sd*bc*sc*i* 
alias:          pci:v00001186d00004C00sv*sd*bc*sc*i* 
alias:          pci:v00001186d00004B03sv*sd*bc*sc*i* 
alias:          pci:v00001186d00004B02sv*sd*bc*sc*i* 
alias:          pci:v00001186d00004B01sv*sd*bc*sc*i* 
alias:          pci:v00001186d00004001sv*sd*bc*sc*i* 
alias:          pci:v00001148d00009E01sv*sd*bc*sc*i* 
alias:          pci:v00001148d00009E00sv*sd*bc*sc*i* 
alias:          pci:v00001148d00009000sv*sd*bc*sc*i* 
alias:          pci:v00001148d00004320sv*sd*bc*sc*i* 
depends:        
vermagic:       3.2.0-39-generic SMP mod_unload modversions 
parm:           Speed_A:array of charp 
parm:           Speed_B:array of charp 
parm:           AutoNeg_A:array of charp 
parm:           AutoNeg_B:array of charp 
parm:           DupCap_A:array of charp 
parm:           DupCap_B:array of charp 
parm:           FlowCtrl_A:array of charp 
parm:           FlowCtrl_B:array of charp 
parm:           Role_A:array of charp 
parm:           Role_B:array of charp 
parm:           ConType:array of charp 
parm:           WolType:array of charp 
parm:           IntsPerSec:array of int 
parm:           Moderation:array of charp 
parm:           ModerationMask:array of charp 
parm:           LowLatency:array of charp 
parm:           TxModeration:array of int 
parm:           MsiIrq:array of charp 
parm:           RSS:array of charp
```

Dec 04,

OK I got it this far :

```
lspci -k | grep -A5 Ethernet 
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Marvell Technology Group Ltd. 88E8056 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 20) 
    Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. Device 0e0a 
    Kernel driver in use: sk98lin 
    Kernel modules: sk98lin, sky2 
03:06.0 FireWire (IEEE 1394): Texas Instruments TSB43AB23 IEEE-1394a-2000 Controller (PHY/Link) 
    Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. Device 0e0a 
hans@hans-GA-78LMT-S2P:~$ ifconfig -a 
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1c:25:51:24:43  
          inet6 addr: fe80::21c:25ff:fe51:2443/64 Scope:Link 
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1 
          RX packets:105 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 
          TX packets:2 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:7491 (7.4 KB)  TX bytes:188 (188.0 B) 
          Interrupt:42 Memory:fdcfc000-0 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0 
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host 
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1 
          RX packets:104 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0 
          TX packets:104 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0 
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:8224 (8.2 KB)  TX bytes:8224 (8.2 KB) 

hans@hans-GA-78LMT-S2P:~$
```

But Ubuntu still reports the cable unplugged.
Any suggestions?

Hans

Dec 6.
Anders:- Here is the lsmod output :-

```
hans@hans-GA-78LMT-S2P:~$ lsmod -a 
Usage: lsmod 
hans@hans-GA-78LMT-S2P:~$ lsmod 
Module                  Size  Used by 
snd_hda_codec_realtek   224173  1 
k8temp                 13057  0 
snd_hda_intel          33719  3 
snd_hda_codec         127706  2 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel 
snd_hwdep              17764  1 snd_hda_codec 
snd_pcm                97275  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec 
snd_seq_midi           13324  0 
snd_rawmidi            30748  1 snd_seq_midi 
snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi 
snd_seq                61929  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event 
snd_timer              29990  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq 
snd_seq_device         14540  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq 
psmouse                97485  0 
sp5100_tco             13791  0 
snd                    79041  15 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device 
i2c_piix4              13301  0 
serio_raw              13211  0 
edac_core              53746  0 
edac_mce_amd           23709  0 
soundcore              15091  1 snd 
snd_page_alloc         18529  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm 
radeon                808704  2 
bnep                   18281  2 
rfcomm                 47604  0 
bluetooth             180153  10 bnep,rfcomm 
parport_pc             32866  1 
ppdev                  17113  0 
ttm                    76949  1 radeon 
drm_kms_helper         46978  1 radeon 
drm                   241971  4 radeon,ttm,drm_kms_helper 
i2c_algo_bit           13423  1 radeon 
mac_hid                13253  0 
shpchp                 37201  0 
lp                     17799  0 
parport                46562  3 parport_pc,ppdev,lp 
usbhid                 47238  0 
firewire_ohci          41000  0 
hid                    99636  1 usbhid 
pata_atiixp            13204  0 
firewire_core          63600  1 firewire_ohci 
crc_itu_t              12707  1 firewire_core 
floppy                 70207  0 
sk98lin               187175  1 
usb_storage            49243  0 
hans@hans-GA-78LMT-S2P:~$
```

I can only see one Ethernet driver loaded. (sk98lin)
Could it be the Network Manager GUI?

Hans

Dec 6 Edit 2

Have tried a number of things,

Static IP - loads it but does not connect to router
Eliminated possible IP conflict on routers - still no results.
I has to be Ubuntu, Here is the working Windows ipconfig.

Microsoft Windows XP [Version 5.1.2600]
(C) Copyright 1985-2001 Microsoft Corp.

C:\Documents and Settings\Hans>ipconfig

Windows IP Configuration

```
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 2:

        Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : royaume.com
        IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.106
        Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
        Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1

C:\Documents and Settings\Hans>ipconfig/all

Windows IP Configuration

        Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : SERVER_1
        Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
        Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Unknown
        IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
        WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
        DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : royaume.com

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 2:

        Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : royaume.com
        Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Marvell Yukon 88E8056 PCI-E Gigabit
Ethernet Controller
        Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-1C-25-51-24-43
        Dhcp Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
        Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
        IP Address. . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.106
        Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
        Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
        DHCP Server . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
        DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
        Lease Obtained. . . . . . . . . . : Friday, December 06, 2013 1:18:08 PM

        Lease Expires . . . . . . . . . . : Saturday, December 07, 2013 1:18:08
PM
```

C:\Documents and Settings\Hans>

So if anyone has an idea? Please I'm now well beyond my knowledge of this OS.

Thanks
Hans

Here is the Dec 7 output:

```
hans@hans-GA-78LMT-S2P:~$ sudo cat ../../etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/* 
[802-3-ethernet] 
duplex=full 
mac-address=00:1C:25:51:24:43 

[connection] 
id=Wired connection 1 
uuid=d10d591a-43b6-4692-84e3-6bd53c5f4f41 
type=802-3-ethernet 

[ipv6] 
method=auto 

[ipv4] 
method=auto 
hans@hans-GA-78LMT-S2P:~$ cat ../../etc/network/interfaces 
auto eth0 
iface eth0 inet static 
    address 192.168.0.106 
    netmask 255.255.255.0 
    network 192.168.0.1 

auto lo 
iface lo inet loopback 


hans@hans-GA-78LMT-S2P:~$
```

Hans

ISSUE SOLVED !!!!

Hi all who were following this.
I have solved the problem.
I still don't know what caused the problem but I have solved it by installing a new PCI Network Card ( StarTech.com part # ST1000BT32.
I disabled the onboard Ethernet and plugged in this card.
Started up LINUX and "BING" a network connection.

So Thanks all who took the time to try to help, especially Anders.

Hope this helps some others.

Happy New Year.

Hans

Comment: Did you update initramfs after blacklisting the driver? - http://askubuntu.com/a/219134/178596

Comment: No I did not update initramfs.
looked at the link but unsure of what it does- so I hesitate to try it.

Comment: You did update the initramfs? I suspect both modules to be loaded atm, causing an interference leading the sk98lin module to fail correct operation.

Comment: Response to Anders in body above.

Comment: Just updated post with new info. Added Win ipconfig output. This works well!

Comment: yes, it seems like we got the driver module loaded as intended. Have you tried to delete the connection in the GUI `networkmanager->edit connection` and then clicked on the networkmanger again and click on `Auto ethernet`? Can you add the output of `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `sudo cat /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/*`

Comment: OK - Tried to find "auto Ethernet" but it does not appear in my  GUI networkmanager. Added interfaces and system-connections to original post. NOTE; Static IP listing as auto does not seem to work.

Comment: had a look at the updated answer?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your case right, and you have not already done so; delete the old network card from `/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules`

**Reason**:
The blacklist tells Ubuntu not to load it on detection of the hardware. If you have a configuration telling it explicit to load it later or another module depending on it loads, will it still be loaded. Unless you have also told Ubuntu how to "load" that module, look at the example, here we specify it to just run /bin/true or /bin/false instead of loading the module with modprobe eg.

**Updated and corrected for your case:**

Add one new line with the name of the module, `sk98lin`, at the end of this file `/etc/modules`. Now are we telling Ubuntu to load the sk98lin driver module at boot.

Then create the file `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-marvell.conf` and add the following on a line
`install sky2 /bin/false`

Then run `sudo depmod -ae`

And yes, you will need to update your init-ram-filesystem with the command `sudo update-initramfs -u`

Restart.

---

If the above should not work for any strange reason, just remove all changes you did and try to do the dirty rc.local hack.

```
# Add the following to your '/etc/rc.local' file.
modprobe -r sky2
modprobe -r sk98lin
modprobe sk98lin
```

Save and restart.

### Answer for followup question

The content of `/etc/network/interfaces` should be

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

You have to either let the NetworkManager or the system(the interfaces file) configure your connection.

To let the NetworkManager do it, delete your old connection and click as picture show.

[image: NetworkManager, Auto Ethernet Ubuntu 12.04]

Comment: Hi Andrew, Just tried your suggestion.

Comment: Hi Andrew,  The system just re added the PCI device to the file.???
What do you mean by /etc/modprobe/ "whatever"?
Hans

Comment: Anders, I'm currently running in Windows on another machine.
I can cut and paste the file content but no way of linking it to a url.

Comment: Anders, did that.
Bold text is # out small test is active.

Comment: ok, delete the file `sudo rm /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules` then reboot and post the new file without editing it.
also add the output of `lsmod | grep "sk98\|sky"` to the question. Also add the output of `modinfo sky` and `modinfo sky98lin`.