# Ubuntu 14.04 on laptop : is there a way to not see my fixed ethernet adapter?

Tags: networking

I have a weird question (usually it's the other way round) but is there a way to fool my Ubuntu installation into thinking that there is no network connection? I only want to establish a network connection when using a USB WiFi dongle. I don't want the computer to see any other adapters (whether plugged in or not).

How do I disable my gigabit ethernet port and all sub-layers (Don't even want the adapter to be "found by hardware")?

Comment: you can just block all the ports so you won't be able to use an internet connection, is that like what you want? But you can also simply disable networking like in given answer by **gyropyge**

Comment: no see "steeldriver's" suggestion below - thats more or less what im looking for.....

Answer (score 1):

In increasing order of medievalness:

1. tell network-manager to ignore the device by [unmanaging](https://askubuntu.com/a/22166/178692) it based on its MAC address
2. [blacklist the kernel module](https://askubuntu.com/questions/219132/blacklist-ethernet-driver) for the device, so that the kernel won't load the driver
3. disable the device in the computer's BIOS

Comment: This is more of what im looking for..  I will try all of these in the order you suggested...... i dont want the system to even know there is a hard wired ethernet port (want it to not find the MAC address) - i will try this - hopefully it works if not - perhaps someone can suggest something akin to this ......

Comment: Or even more medievalness:  4. Download the service manual for your hardware, open up the laptop and yank out the port and chipset responsible for the on-board LAN.  No NIC?  No driver!  **>:)**

Answer (score 0):

I've used 14.04 as recent as yesterday but never had your need.  I'm using 12.04 at the moment, so this might not apply.  Please right click on your internet connection icon at the top of your screen and where you see, "enable networking" check, uncheck that.

If that's not what you want to do, please clarify.